# How to get the model id from BelongsTo relationship?

Tags: laravel

I tried `$this->id` but it returns nothing with artisan tinker:

```
class Part extends Model
{
    ...

    public function inv(): BelongsTo
    {
        echo "foo\n";
        echo $this->id . "\n";
        return $this->belongsTo(
            Inv::class,
            'surv_id',
            'surv_id'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: lacks information about where this inv() function/relation is called. Provide more info about the controller and the model instance that calls the inv() relation

Comment: @FarhanIbnWahid I have updated my question : I need to get the `$part` `id` from inside the model's BelongsTo method

Comment: @DevonDahon thats not possible to echo within the relation method because it is the part of query builder. Why you need it if you define your proper query about what you want actually then we will be able to give you a proper solution.

Comment: @M-Khawar I needed to add something like `->where('user_id', $this->user_id)` to the `belongsTo` query, but for this I need to be able to access the model's attributes columns

Comment: I understand what you are trying to achieve, please provide where the `Part` model instance `$part` is used in your controller or view

Comment: @FarhanIbnWahid For test purpose, I'm currently just using it like this in artisan tinker: `Part::with('inv')->latest()->first()`

Comment: is there any error in tinker output? I tried to replicate your situation and getting `$this->id` printed on `tinker` successfully with no issue, only change I made is removed the relation return type `: BelongsTo`

Comment: @FarhanIbnWahid I have no error, `$this->id` is just null, even without `: BelongsTo`

Comment: please share the database tables also and check if the foreign-keys are properly created

Comment: @DevonDahon I have added an answer please checkout and let me know If I understand wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to debug relationship, best way is to install `laravel/telescope`, (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/telescope) in that way you can view what's happening when you query your relationship.

One way to test the primaryKeys when debugging is try putting absurd column name like `survvvvvvv_id` just to see what's happening.

Comment: `$this->survvvvvvv_id` returns null as well

Answer (score 0):

As you said in a comment you want to filter `Inv` model records against `user_id` in relation. The solution I found is using raw query with relation.

```
public function inv(): BelongsTo
{

   return $this->belongsTo( Inv::class,'surv_id','surv_id')->whereRaw('invs.user_id = parts.user_id');

}
```

> **Note:** Here in `whereRaw` clause I'm supposing your model `Inv::class` is using `invs` database `table name`. If your database table has a different name then please replace it with the appropriate name according to your table.

I hope that will work for you.